# SKScene like a planet (simulate a sphere)

Tags: ios

I'm writing a 2D game using Sprite kit in iOS.
In few words, my game should show a spaceship which navigates around a planet.
So my main scene should simulate a sphere (like a planet), and will be rectangular on my 2D plan (attached to SKView).
What I want to do is when the spaceship will leave the screen from one side (let's say left side) with a given direction, immediately I want to see it appearing from the opposite side (right side, or bottom side, according to the angle formed by the direction vector) with the same direction and the same velocity.
How can I to do that ?

here below my code:

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics{
       [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:(NSString*)spaceShipName usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) { 
CGPoint newPosition;
    if (node.position.x < 0 || node.position.x > self.view.frame.size.width || node.position.y < 0 || node.position.y > self.view.frame.size.height)
    {
        newPosition = [self calculateNextPoint:node.position velocity:node.physicsBody.velocity];
        [node setPosition:newPosition];
    }}];
}
```

all the problem is to code the function named calculateNextPoint ... I tried to use some mathematical theorems without success (it was too heavy).

Thanks for all